# Optimizing ManyToMany (ToMany) Django query

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I still have a lot to learn about Django models, so be gentle.
Consider this model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Community(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Portal(models.Model):
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community, blank=True, null=True)

class Page(models.Model):
    portals = models.ManyToManyField(Portal, null=True)
```

So a Page can be in many Portals. Each Portal has a Community and a Community has many users.
Now I'm trying to find all the users related to a single page:

```
def allowed_users(self):
    return User.objects.filter(community__in=Community.objects.filter(portal__in=self.portals.all()))
```

This works, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing it. Possibly with Q or F. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which model does `allowed_users` belong to ?

Comment: allowed_users belongs to Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the double-underscore syntax to traverse relationships. Assuming `allowed_users` is a method on `Page`:

```
User.objects.filter(community__portal__page=self)
```

Comment: Excellent. This was just what I was looking from